# Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'

Tags: fedora

When I try update or install a package, fedora 25 show me this message

```
  Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'7%
```

How I can fix that problem?

Comment: Looks like broken `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo` file. How does that file look like on your system?